# MySQL AES_Decrypt not working

Tags: mysql, aes

I've been trying so many different variations to get AES_Decrypt to work. I started of with field types VARBINARY then tried BLOB but still no luck, keeps returning NULL. Eventually I tried this:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('blah blah blah','1234'), '1234') as test
```

This technically should have returned blah blah blah, but instead it returns

```
 626c616820626c616820626c6168
```

So not sure what is going on or what I am doing wrong.

I have inserted encrypted data as follows:

```
INSERT INTO private (short_name, mobile, name) 
VALUES (
  'AS1', 
  AES_ENCRYPT('0111222333','1234'), 
  AES_ENCRYPT('My Name','1234')
)
```

Then I try to decrypt it like this:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT('mobile', '1234') AS mobile FROM private
```

It just does not seem to work. Followed lots of the instructions online but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that I need to use CAST unless using the mysql command line client.

So doing this seems to work:

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('blah blah blah','1234'), '1234') AS CHAR (150))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('blah blah blah','1234'), '1234') as test
```

is returning binary string as output. If you convert it to string then it will blah blah blah. You can use online hex to binary converter to verify it. You have to set it to text in your GUI tool.

Comment: I tried converting the string using online binary convertor but all give errors. Is there not supposed to be a way to return it as text without having to seperately convert it

Comment: ok it seems I need to put it like this: SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('blah blah blah','1234'), '1234') AS CHAR (150))

Comment: Select UNHEX('626c616820626c616820626c6168'); It will show you blah blah blah.